# play scala ';' expected but '@' found error at controllers's @Inject()

Tags: scala, drop-down-menu, playframework, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I am new to `play scala frame work`,in my project I would like to select `multiple values in drop down` for this purpose I had used http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ this plugin in my `select.scala.html` and added the required `.css,.js` files
**select.scala.html**

```
 @import helper._

@(field: play.api.data.Field, options: Seq[(String,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)
<html>
<head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap-select.css")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap-select.min.css")">
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-select.js")"></script> 
</head>

@input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    @defining( if( htmlArgs.contains('multiple) ) "%s[]".format(name) else name ) { selectName =>
    @defining( ( !field.indexes.isEmpty && htmlArgs.contains('multiple) ) match {
            case true => field.indexes.map( i => field("[%s]".format(i)).value ).flatten.toSet
            case _ => field.value.toSet
    }){ values =>
        <select id="@id" name="@selectName" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs) class="selectpicker" multiple> 
            @args.toMap.get('_default).map { defaultValue =>
                <option class="blank" value="">@defaultValue</option>
            }
            @options.map { v =>
                <option value="@v._1" @if(values.contains(v._1)){selected="selected"}>@v._2</option>
            }
        </select>
    }}
}
</body>
</html>
```

**Employees.scala** `controller class`

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import views._
import models._
import play.api.i18n.Messages._

object Employees @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi)  extends Controller with I18nSupport { 
---
----
}
```

When I compile my project it shows the below error

```
D:\employee>activator compile
[info] Loading project definition from D:\employee\project
[info] Set current project to employee(in build file:/D:/employee/)
[info] Compiling 37 Scala sources and 1 Java source to D:\employee\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] D:\employee\app\controll
ers\Employees.scala:11: ';' expected but '@' found.
[error] object Employees @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi)  extends Contr
oller   with I18nSupport {
[error]                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed please help me to fix this issue.
```

Comment: What version do you see in `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.2")` inside `project/plugins.sbt` in your project?

Comment: my `plugins.sbt` contains `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.9")`

Answer (score 0):

You should use classes. Objects have different scope and lifecycle than guice managed dependencies.

`class Employees @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi)`

Comment: If I use `class Employees @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi)  extends Controller with I18nSupport { `
it shows below errors in `eclipse`
`not found: type Inject`,
`not found: type MessagesApi`,
`not found: type I18nSupport`

Comment: Your imports are broken. Try importing `javax.inject.Inject` and the rest.

Comment: `javax` doesn't contain the `inject` package but it has `accessibility`,`annotation`,`activity`,`crypto`,etc..

Comment: It shows error as `object inject is not a member of package javax`

Comment: As MonCalamari said you cannot inject into object. It's possible that object will be instantiated before injectables. Problem with imports most probably related to your project build settings or java/scala version. You miss at least this  `import play.api.i18n.I18nSupport`. Update your message with your build files (like build.sbt or Build.scala)